# What are the differences between the pronunciation of "bidet" in American and British English?

Tags: pronunciation, american-english

What are the differences between the pronunciation of *bidet* in American English, and British English?

The last part of the word sounds like the pronunciation of *day*, in both the cases. I don't understand the differences for the first part of the word.

Are there other words that have the same differences in the pronunciation?

Comment: As a Brit, I say *BEE-day*, but [this site](http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=bidet) says Americans say *bi-DAY*. Nothing unusual there. Americans often stress different syllables and pronounce things oddly - witness [Iraq/Iran](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070124110122AAy41U0)

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers- as an American I say bih-DAY (*bih* as in *big*, *bid*, *billow*) unless I'm emphasizing the French pronunciation in which case I might say bee-DAY.

Comment: [Beaches & bitches](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/260/pronunciation-of-beaches-and-bitches) again

Comment: Most Americans don't often use or encounter the word *bidet*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that with *bidet*, as also with words like *ballet, beret, buffet, café, cliché,* and *debris*, in North America the stress falls on the second syllable, while Britain favors the first syllable in each of those words.

[Wikipedia calls this “French stress”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_pronunciation_differences#French_stress), and has quite a long list of these.  A few of those are wrong, though, like for example *négligée*, which is stressed on the first syllable in both but which receives secondary stress at the end in North America.

Comment: Just to be clear "French stress" for French speakers is universally "a slight elongation of the final syllable in each rhythmic group" (much weaker than English stress in English words or in the borrowed words).  In the Wikipedia article "French stress" only means "Stress (in English) of French origin words"

Comment: Presumably this also explains why Americans usually say ***fi-LAY*** for ***FILL-et*** [steak].

Answer (score 5):

French has much lighter syllable stress than English does. In French, all the syllables have equal or almost equal weighting, whereas in English almost all words have emphasis on the first syllable (with exceptions, of course, because English is good at pronunciation exceptions).

On neither side of the Atlantic do we pronounce the word as it would be spoken natively: in Britain we ignore the foreign emphasis entirely and stress syllables the same as we would if it were an English word (i.e. put emphasis on the first syllable); whereas in American English the difference (of the foreign word from English) is emphasized, so the emphasis comes on the final syllable: bi-DAY, bu-FAY, etc.

Answer (score 0):

## You asked about the word "**bidet**"

I cannot write faithfully about the British pronunciation.

However, Americans like myself have 18 different pronunciations for the word "bidet".

It is difficult to say with certainty which of the 18 pronunciations appears with the greatest frequency in spoken conversations. I have never conducted a survey on such things.

The pronunciation I am most familiar with, sounds like the sentence "***I*** bid ***you good*** day" with the emboldened italicized words deleted. It sounds like "bid-day".

---

## American Vowels

Americans have 7 different vowels which their eyes perceive when writing `AEUIOU` and sometimes `Y`

Americans have 8, or more, different vowels which their ears perceive when listening with their ears.

| Ad Hoc Phonetic Spelling | Standard Spelling of Words which Use the Auditory Vowel When Spoken Aloud | Words Spelled Phonetically |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AW | cross, awl, all, brought, call, draw, fall, gone, hall, raw, saw, law | kraws, awl, awl, brawt, cawl, draw, fawl, gawn, hawl, raw, saw, law |
| AH | add, and, bad, band, grand, had, hand, man, plan, stand | ah-d, ah-nd, b-ah-d, b-ah-nd, gr-ah-nd, h-ah-d, h-ah-nd, m-ah-n, pl-ah-n, st-ah-nd |
| EH | any, bed, best, cell, echo, dead, end, bend, send, rend, lend, tend | eh-ny, b-eh-d, b-eh-st, s-eh-ll, eh-ko, d-eh-d, eh-nd, beh-nd, seh-nd, reh-nd, leh-nd, teh-nd |
| UH | above, among, umbrella, come, blood, but, of, oven, under, wonder, sunder, unearth | uh-b-uh-v, uh-m-uh-ng, uh-mbr-uh-ll-uh, c-uh-m, bl-uh-d, b-uh-t, uh-f, uh-v-eh-n, uh-ndur, w-uh-nder, s-uh-nder, uh-n-urth |
| IH | did, grid, hid, if, in, into, is, it, kid, lid, rid, skid, slid, squid, this, which, will, with |  |
| OH | bone, bow, grow, home, know, low, no, own, phone, show, stone, tone, tow, zone |  |
| EE | agree, be, bead, beam, bee, creed, deep, free, he, key, knee, need, plea, read, reed, sea, see, seed, seem, she, speed, tea, thee, three, tree, we |  |
| OO | assume, balloon, bloom, boom, commune, consume, costume, doom, gloom, immune, june, noon, perfume, presume, resume, room, soon, spoon, tomb, tune, whom, womb |  |
| AW-EE | buy, die, eye, fly, high, lie, pie, sky, tie |  |
| EH-EE | (English able, age, base, pain, rain, sane, lane, brain, cane, day, bay, Lay, May, Nay, Pay, Ray, Say, Way, Yay) (Spanish `de`, `deberes`, `el`, `en`, `encender`, `entre`, `es`, `ver`) |  |

---

## Choosing the Vowel Close to the End of the Word `Bidet`

### Choice One of Two `AY` or `EH-EE`

There exist times at which the suffix "**det**" on the word "**bidet**" is pronounced such that it rhymes with the following words:

> - Bay
> - Hay
> - Lay
> - May
> - Nay
> - Pay
> - Ray
> - Say
> - Way
> - Yay

---

### Choice Two of Two `EH`

There exist times at which the suffix "**det**" on the word "**bidet**" is pronounced such that it rhymes with the following strings. Some of the following strings are prefixes or post-fixes rather than entire American English words:

> - beset
> - bet
> - cassette
> - debt
> - forget
> - gazette
> - get
> - jet
> - let
> - met
> - net
> - pet
> - quartet
> - regret
> - reset
> - set
> - silhouette
> - sweat
> - threat
> - upset
> - vet
> - wet
> - yet

---

Americans, such as myself, sometimes find that the relationship between written vowels and spoken auditory vowels is difficult to comprehend.

> - There are three ways to choose how to pronounce the left-most vowel "i" in "b **I** det"
> - There are three ways to choose how to pronounce the right-most vowel "e" in "bid **E** t"
> - There are two ways to choose whether or not to pronounce the letter "t" at the end of the word. Americans who have not been taught how to pronounce French generally do pronounce the letter "t". There are fewer silent consonants in American English than in French.

If we were to try to spell the word "**bidet**" phonetically, we might have the following bizarre spellings:

| Number | First Vowel | Last Vowel | English-Like Spelling | Spanish-Like Spelling |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AW-EE | AW-EE | `B-AW-EE-D-AW-EE` | `BaiDai` |
| 2 | AW-EE | AW-EE | `B-AW-EE-D-AW-EE-T` | `BaiDait` |
| 3 | AW-EE | IH | `B-AW-EE-D-IH` | `Baid(ih)` |
| 4 | AW-EE | IH | `B-AW-EE-D-IH-T` | `Baid(ih)t` |
| 5 | AW-EE | EE | `B-AW-EE-D-EE` | `Baidi` |
| 6 | AW-EE | EE | `B-AW-EE-D-EE-T` | `BaiDit` |
| 7 | IH | AW-EE | `B-IH-D-AW-EE` | `B(ih)Dai` |
| 8 | IH | AW-EE | `B-IH-D-AW-EE-T` | `B(ih)Dait` |
| 9 | IH | IH | `B-IH-D-IH` | `B(ih)D(ih)` |
| 10 | IH | IH | `B-IH-D-IH-T` | `B(ih)D(ih)t` |
| 11 | IH | EE | `B-IH-D-EE` | `BiDi` |
| 12 | IH | EE | `B-IH-D-EE-T` | `B(ih)dit` |
| 13 | EE | AW-EE | `B-EE-D-AW-EE` | `BiDai` |
| 14 | EE | AW-EE | `B-EE-D-AW-EE-T` | `BiDawit` |
| 15 | EE | IH | `B-EE-D-IH` | `Bead` |
| 16 | EE | IH | `B-EE-D-IH-T` | `Bid(ih)t` |
| 17 | EE | EE | `B-EE-D-EE` | `Bidi` |
| 18 | EE | EE | `B-EE-D-EE-T` | `BiDit` |

Spanish spelling would be more elegant than American English spelling, except that, in Spain, they rarely use the vowels `ih`, `eh`, `uh`, or `ah`.

The set of all vowels used in Spain is a proper subset of the set of all vowels used in North America (Canada, the USA, et cetra).

| Ad Hoc Phonetic Spelling | In English? | In Spanish? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `AW` | In Vocal/Auditory English | In Vocal/Auditory Spanish |
| `AH` | In Vocal/Auditory English | ***rare*** and ***uncommon*** in Vocal/Auditory Spanish |
| `EH` | In Vocal/Auditory English | Almost always followed by `EE` in Vocal/Auditory Spanish |
| `UH` | In Vocal/Auditory English | ***rare*** and ***uncommon*** in Vocal/Auditory Spanish |
| `IH` | In Vocal/Auditory English | ***rare*** and ***uncommon*** in Vocal/Auditory Spanish |
| `OH` | In Vocal/Auditory English | In Vocal/Auditory Spanish. Spanish writing is `o` |
| `EE` | In Vocal/Auditory English | In Vocal/Auditory Spanish. Spanish writing is `i` |
| `OO` | In Vocal/Auditory English | In Vocal/Auditory Spanish. Spanish writing is `u` |
| `AW` - `EE` | In Vocal/Auditory English | In Vocal/Auditory Spanish. Spanish writing is `ai` |
| `EH` - `EE` | In Vocal/Auditory English | In Vocal/Auditory Spanish. Spanish writing is `e` |